# Java RegEx Syntax with Word Boundaries?

Tags: java, regex, word-boundaries

Firstly, my syntax will not be part of a script as such but it will be parsed via a form input--so any 'existing' solution pointing to Java code will not apply per se.

Okay, so here is what I need to do: I need to be able to input a term like:

'This is your airport and this is your car.' into an input field in such a way that only the word 'airport' or 'airports' to be matched. So nothing like '99airport' or 'airport99' should be matched. And I am close!

```
(?i).*\bair[port|ports].*
```

If I input the above as RegEx in a test site:

http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/#!;t=123-45-6789%0A9876-5-4321%0A987-65-4321%20(attack)%0A987-65-4321%20%0A192-83-7465&r=(%3Fm)%5E(%5Cd%7B3%7D-%3F%5Cd%7B2%7D-%3F%5Cd%7B4%7D)%24&x=Found%20good%20SSN%3A%20%241

then, indeed, '99airport' does not match because of the beginning use of the Word Boundary identifier `\b` ; However, I don't know how to put the \b around the  ending of the word so that 'airport99' also does not match. I have tried a few things but no luck. I think it is the syntax to be put around the [] which needs to be figured out.

And *please don't pay too much attention to what needs to be matched or not--these are just random words*. Currently, if my input has 'airport99' it does get matched but it shouldn't if I can figure out a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `(?i).*\bairports?\b.*`. In Java, `String patrn = "(?i).*\\bairports?\\b.*";`

Comment: Thanks. That would work except I also need the possible combinations inside the [ ]; you see, in real life, I am trying to catch words like 'tornado' or 'Tornado' or 'ToRNADOES' while preventing to catch 'FCGTornadoTeam' .

Comment: What about `country`/`countries`?

Comment: Yes, that could work as countr with [y|ies]

Comment: You are mistaking groups for character classes. Let me explain in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using `mather.matches` to check for a word inside the input string. That is why you need the `.*` before and after a keyword. Since the text is coming from an input field, you do not need to match newline symbols, and no need in `(?s)` singleline/dotall modifier.

However, you mistake [character classes (`[...]`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with [groups (`(...)`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Character classes match 1 character. For example, `[port|ports]` matches 1 character, either `p`, `o`, `r`, `t`, `|`, or `s`. Groups can be used to match specific *sequences* of symbols. E.g. `(port|ports)` will match either `port` or `ports`.

Thus, in your case, you can use

```
(?i).*\bairports?\b.*
```

or - less effecient -

```
(?i).*\bair(port|ports)\b.*
```

In Java, `String patrn = "(?i).*\\bairports?\\b.*";`

Comment: Yes, (?i).*\bair(port|ports)\b.* does it! My problem was using [ ] instead of () to catch port|ports. I will see if this will work inside the actual program or not--it should. Thanks for your help and the explanation. New to RegEx and not really a Java person.

Comment: I really would like to stress the fact that just using `ports?` (where `s?` matches *1 or 0 `s`*) is a better alternative to `(port|ports)`. For country/countries, you can't escape using an alternative groups, but wherever possible, just use optional quantifier `?` (1 or 0 occurrences). It will involve much less backtracking, and improve performance. Well, if your input strings are short, that should not be a problem. Just best practices are best practices :)

Answer (score 1):

This expression should match your requirements:

```
(?i)\\b(air)?port\\b
```

It does match "port" and "airport" but does not match "99port" nor "port99" nor "99airport" neither "airport99".

If a more generic expression is needed, this one should match any word starting with "air" plus some other (optional) letters, but no digits or punctuation symbols:

```
(?i)\\b(air)?[a-z]*\\b
```

Comment: I admit maybe I didn't phrase the question 100% correctly--if I could just prevent both '99airport' and 'airport99' to match while still retaining the possible words inside the [ ] then that would be all I need. I still need to account for what is inside [ ] and not sure your solution accounts for that. Apologies.

Comment: Hehe. Yes, it happens :-) I suggest you include in your question several examples of what should be matched and other examples of what should not be matched.

Comment: Thanks for understanding. Rephrased the question.

Comment: Thanks! I think stribizhev's Answer perfectly matches the requirements; I was close but was using [ ] instead of () to catch the port or ports possibilities.